# In windows, how to copy a particular subdirectory from each directory?

Tags: windows

In Windows, how can I copy from *source* to *destination*, with directory filter. The filter should look something like this: `*\app\src` which means: for each *source* subfolder ("each" means matching `*`) find subfolder `app\src` and copy it to *destination* preserving folder structure.

I tried robocopy but it says *ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "*\app\src\"*:

```
robocopy C:\Projects C:\backup  *\app\src\
```

How to do it? (not necessarily in robocopy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a batch file,

- as a recursive `/s` dir can only have one name
- findstr is used to match only lines ending with both dirs
- in the found dir string the base name is exchanged with dest to form the proper destination folder name.

---

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Base=C:\Projects\"
Set "Dest=C:\backup\"
Set "Dir1=app"
Set "Dir2=src"

For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S/AD "%Base%\%Dir2%" ^|findstr /LEI "\%Dir1%\%Dir2%" '
) Do (
  Set "CopyTo=%%A"
  Set "CopyTo=!CopyTo:%Base%=%Dest%!\"
  If not Exist "!CopyTo!" Echo MD "!CopyTo!"
  Echo robo/x/copy "%%~fA\*" "!CopyTo!"
)
```

If the output looks OK remove the echos in the last two lines and adjust the copy command.

Comment: I ended up with the last line: `robocopy %%~fA !CopyTo! /e` and it's doing well, thanks.

Comment: without double qoutes it won't handle path/file names containing spaces.

Comment: Indeed, without quotes it reports error if directory name has a space. On the other hand, if quotes are present as original, then robocopy complains that `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` It also reports the following summary:  `Source : C:\Projects\MyTestProject\app\src\     Dest : C:\Backup\MyTestProject\app\src"\\` As you can see, the Dest looks strange (backslash after quote).

Comment: I tested with xcopy - works unchanged, I'm not that familiar with the robocopy options.